# How to Login with OTP in react native using Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, native

getting this error when I Implement the code which is given below the error...

#### [Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.]

I want to add functionality to the user can login with otp.. but when I add the code which is picked from 'React native Firebase' then it is throwing the error

Login Screen:
how to solve the error or provide me the steps to solve this ...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const OTPLoginScreen = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');

  const sendOtp = async () => {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+91'+phoneNumber);
      setVerificationId(confirmation.verificationId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Enter your phone number:</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Phone Number"
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
      />
      <Button title="Send OTP" onPress={sendOtp} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default OTPLoginScreen;
```